# BuildprocessTemplate running InvokeProcess, getting "File not found"

Tags: build-server, build-process-template

I am trying to run a batch file as part of my build with the `InvokeProcess` activity. However any combination of `FileName` and `WorkingDirectory` makes the build fail with the "File not found: *NameOfMyBatchFile.bat*" message. Any tips on how to troubleshoot this better?

I have tried putting the entire path in the "FileName" property, and likewise in the "WorkingDirectory" property. The file I am trying to run is under the D:\ disk on my buildserver where the Build Controller and Agents are.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the build with Verbosity = Diagnostics, and see the exact value that is getting passed into the InvokeProcess activity at runtime.